# How do I display an alert to the main-page.php, when the data is inserted successfully or not

Tags: php, mysql

[THIS IS THE THE MAIN-PAGE.PHP upon clicking on the add button a modal will appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCq5r.png)

[THIS IS THE FORM THAT I PUT IN A BOOTSRAP MODAL, the form has an action="add.php" which is a seperated php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dZdr.png)

this is the add.php code, I don't know how to display the $status on main-page.php because it is in the add.php file.

```
$run_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)  or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error($conn), E_USER_ERROR);
if ($run_sql===true){
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_profile_img,"upload/$profile_img");

    $status = '<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong>The data has been inserted SUCCESSFULLY</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>';
}
else{
    $status = '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong>The data was NOT inserted SUCCESSFULLY</strong> Please try again.
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>';
}

header("Location:main-page.php");
?>
```

Comment: when you change the page with `header("Location:main-page.php");` you can't show any message in previous page

Comment: Stick the message into a session variable, and have `main-page.php` display it if it contains anything?

Comment: How do you call the PHP code? Are you using Ajax, or just a standard form submit?

Comment: standard form submit

Comment: does putting the php code written above in a seperate file will work, or should I include it inside main-page.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send query to the main-page.php , like this

```
header("Location:main-page.php?status=success");
```

in the main-page.php, you can get  it, link this

```
$status = isset($_GET["status"]) ? $_GET["status"] : null
```

Comment: this looks good, but i don't understand the second one, Im just a beginner in PHP, can you please elaborate it for me, thanks!

Comment: $_GET can collect data sent in the URL.
i use this for get status in query

Answer (score 0):

this worked
main-page.php

```
<?php 
            if(isset($_GET['status']) AND $_GET['status'] == 'success'){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>';
             }elseif(isset($_GET['status']) AND $_GET['status'] == 'fail'){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>';
             }else{
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>';
             }
        ?>
```

add.php

```
$run_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)  or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error($conn), E_USER_ERROR);
if ($run_sql===true){
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_profile_img,"upload/$profile_img");
    header("Location:main-page.php?status=success");
}
else{
    header("Location:main-page.php?status=fail");
}
```

but I don't know if it's a clean code

Comment: You can create a function on the main-page.php and put the html code in it.

Comment: Please consider enabling error reporting for mysqli. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)